# Javascript code to toggle the green and red color every 3 sec only on desktop view

Tags: javascript, toggle

I'm trying to make a webpage change the 2 div tags with colors red and green  every three seconds using JavaScript.

Comment: Please do not do that. It will probably just annoy the majority of the visitors of your website, if they change their colours all the time. In general, any such effects should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved in two ways: `pure javascript` or `JQuery`

#### Pure Javasript

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
  var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
  if(div1.className == 'green') {
    div1.className = '';
  } else {
    div1.className = 'green';
  }
  if(div2.className == 'red') {
    div2.className = '';
  } else {
    div2.className = 'red';
  } 
}, 3000);
```

```css
#div1 {
  background: red;
 }

#div2 {
  background: green;
 }

.red {
  background:red !important;
 }

.green {
  background: green !important;
 }
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="green">
  div1
</div>
<div id="div2" class="red">
  div2
</div>
```

#### For JQuery

You can use Javascript [jquery](https://jquery.com/) library and can do something like this

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {  
  setInterval(function() {
   $('#div1').toggleClass('green');
   $('#div2').toggleClass('red'); 
  }, 3000);
 });
```

```css
#div1 {
  background: red;
 }

#div2 {
  background: green;
 }

.red {
  background:red !important;
 }

.green {
  background: green !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="green">
  div1
</div>
<div id="div2" class="red">
  div2
</div>
```

Hope this will help you in some way (y).

Note: This is not efficient if we consider machine performance.